# Haskell : Integer to Int with int signature

Tags: haskell, integer, int, type-conversion

So i'm having problems with some variable types.

```
getOrdenado :: (String,Int,String,Int,Int) -> Int
getOrdenado (_,_,_,a,_) = a 

listaOrdenado :: [(String,Int,String,Int,Int)] -> [Int]
listaOrdenado xs = map getOrdenado xs
```

**getOrdenado** takes a certain **Int** value from a tuple contained in a list of tuples and **listaOrdenado** makes a list of all of thoose specific **Int**'s.

This function is supposed to work on the following list:

```
firma = [("Ana", 30, "RH", 1500, 3), ("Rui", 40, "Vendas", 1000, 2),
        ("Luis", 45, "RH", 3333, 5), ("Maria", 55, "Admin", 2000, 4)]
```

But whenever i try running **listaOrdenado** with this list i get the following error

```
Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Int'
Expected type: [(String, Int, String, Int, Int)]
  Actual type: [([Char], Integer, [Char], Integer, Integer)]
In the first argument of `listaOrdenado', namely `firma'
In the expression: listaOrdenado firma
In an equation for `it': it = listaOrdenado firma
```

I am not allowed to use **Integer** in the class signature, only **Int** so i have no clue on how to solve this, nor do i have any clue why it says that those values in **firma** are **Integer**'s

Comment: You can force `Int` as the type by putting inline types like `30 :: Int`, or give `firma` a type signature so that it uses `Int` instead of `Integer` (`Integer` is the default)

Comment: Try putting `firma :: [(String, Int, String, Int, Int)]` before the declaration for `firma`.  If you're defining this in GHCi, then put it in a file instead.

Comment: I'm not allowed to give any signature to **firma** , more specifically i'm not allowed to alter anything about **firma**

Comment: Then wherever you *use* `firma` in your code, reference it like this: `(firma :: [(String, Int, String, Int, Int)])`

Comment: So i should add this line to my code:

Comment: You have to put the type signature somewhere, but if you can't change `firma` you can just call `listaOrdenado` in `ghci` like this: `λ> listaOrdenado (firma :: [(String, Int, String, Int, Int)])`

Comment: Firma is not defined in my .hs file since its and hypothetical list to test the functions,  if I simply add that firma signature to my .hs file won't ghci complain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the problem is not solved yet, I edited my answer to be more precise:

If you have top level definitions in your Haskell module, Haskell will infer a **monomorphic** type and not a polymorphic. The reason is very simple. Haskell assumes that a top level definition is used quite often and if an expression has a monomorphic type, it has to be evaluated just ones. In your case, Haskell tries to find the best fitting **monomorphic** type for the numbers in your tuple. By specification/implementation Haskell tries first the type `Integer` and then the type `Float`. This is the reason why you have the type error in your code.

Now you have several options to solve this problem:

1.Add the type of firma in your module (preferred solution):

```
module Test where

getOrdenado :: (String,Int,String,Int,Int) -> Int
getOrdenado (_,_,_,a,_) = a 

listaOrdenado :: [(String,Int,String,Int,Int)] -> [Int]
listaOrdenado xs = map getOrdenado xs

firma :: Num a => [(String,a,String,a,a)]
firma = [("Ana", 30, "RH", 1500, 3), ("Rui", 40, "Vendas", 1000, 2),
        ("Luis", 45, "RH", 3333, 5), ("Maria", 55, "Admin", 2000, 4)]
```

If you call `listaOrdenado firma`, it works just fine for me.

2.The second possibility is to turn off monomorphic type inference by overwriting the used defaults. How this is done is explained in this wiki entry: https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction

3.The last, but quite expensive, solution in my mind is to manually cast the elements of your list to the preferred type.

Comment: Annotating at the use site will only move the type error.

Comment: After adding this line to my code:

    firma :: Num a, Num b, Num c => [(String, a, String, b, c)] i get the following error when trying to load my .hs file onto ghci:

    .hs:1:15: parse error on input `,'

caracter 15 being the first , after **a**

Comment: sorry this was a copy paste error, I updated my answer.

Comment: The parse error is gone but now it gives another error regarding the lack of an accompanying binding:    The type signature for `firma' lacks an accompanying binding

Comment: Can you explain how you use firma? Did you try to manually cast it and then you get this error?

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the signature of `firma`, just add the appropriate type signature to it:

```
firma :: [(String, Int, String, Int, Int)]
firma = [("Ana", 30, "RH", 1500, 3), ("Rui", 40, "Vendas", 1000, 2),
        ("Luis", 45, "RH", 3333, 5), ("Maria", 55, "Admin", 2000, 4)]
```

If not allowed to change `firma`, you can call `listaOrdenado` by giving `firma` a specific type signature on the `ghci` prompt:

```
$ ghci firma.hs
λ> listaOrdenado (firma :: [(String, Int, String, Int, Int)])
```

If `firma` actually has a type signature with `Integer` used, then you need to cast from `Integer` to `Int` using `fromIntegral` in some manner like this:

```
fI = fromIntegral
integerToInt [] = []
integerToInt ((a,b,c,d,e):xs) = (a, fI b, c, fI d, fI e) : (integerToInt xs)
```

and then invoke `listaOrdenado` like this in `ghci`:

```
$ ghci firma.hs
λ> listaOrdenado (integerToInt firma)
```

Comment: The thing is firma is a list that's going to be used to test my code,  firma may have more tuples than the ones I was provided with,  the only firm thing are the types of the variables inside the tuples.                           So I can't like put a version of firma in my . Hs file  nor can I add the specification when calling it for the ghci since I will not be the one calling her when avaluating the functions.                                                   and I do belive firma doesn't have a signature or at least I am not provided with it

Comment: If you're not the one calling `listaOrdenado` and you're not allowed to use `Integer` or `Num` in the type signature, then you can just assume whoever uses your code will pass in the right type because the onus is on the caller to provide the correct types because Haskell is strongly typed.